# GitLab: Commit must be signed with a GPG key

Tags: git, gitlab

I've faced an issue with GitLab, and I don't know how to fix this issue. I'm owner of repository, I've already `gpg` enabled, but at the end I still face an issue. Here is my global configuration for my git:

```
[user]
    name = neon
    email = neon@example.com
    signingkey = 244F9F35
[init]
    defaultBranch = main
[gpg]
    program = gpg
[commit]
    gpgsign = true
[credential]
    helper = store --file ~/.git/.my-credentials
[pull]
    rebase = true
```

Error:

```
remote: GitLab: Commit must be signed with a GPG key
To https://gitlab.com/some_name.git
 ! [remote rejected] cm -> cm (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/some_name.git'
```

Regarding GitLab it self, GPG key has been assigned, and in use

```
neon@example.com Verified D5BF2528338FE1EEC73DDC7F96FBC559244F9F35
```

Comment: It is possible that some commit is not yet signed

Comment: If you run `git log --show-signature`, are all of your commits signed?

Comment: The output says: `Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit. nothing to commit, working tree clean` however I've added all changes and committed with `git commit -S -m "Comment message"`

Comment: To double check, run `git fetch` (or `git fetch origin`) and make sure you're still exactly 1 commit ahead. If so, the problem is that GitLab's verifier does not believe your commit is GPG-signed, even though you see it signed. If you are suddenly 5 commits ahead for instance, though, you'll need to check all five of those commits.

Answer (score 1):

Check on your gitlab account https://gitlab.com/-/profile/emails, that your email `neon@example.com` is verified.

Check your gpg keys on gitlab https://gitlab.com/-/profile/gpg_keys and verified.

> **REMEBER**: GPG is case-sensitive! So check the spelling of your email address.

When you are on Windows or WSL, then may gpg is not part of the path variable and you have to add the path to gpg.exe or use in gitconfig the fullpath